# Unable to export Groups and users list in openerp 7

Tags: odoo

I would like to export **all groups customized by me**, and **all users created by me** in openerp 7, and to import them into another database so that i get all users with their appropirate access rights.

But When i try to export the group details and user details i get the following error.

```
KeyError: u"Field 'in_group_1' does not exist in object 'browse_record(res.users, 1)'"
```

Is it a bug or am i missing something around? Thanks for your clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Groups in Users view is actually a openerp generated view(boolean and selections).Groups are actually a many2many field in users. so you can export this many2many field. or try to export the groups view.